TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') while using my local react npm package
I am getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') while using my local react npm package.
My npm package built with react, typescript and bundled using webpack.
my webpack.config.json
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    library: "package-name",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    globalObject: "this",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".css"],
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react"),
      "react-dom": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-dom"),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.css$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: "React",
      commonjs2: "react",
      commonjs: "react",
      amd: "react",
    },
    "react-dom": {
      root: "ReactDOM",
      commonjs2: "react-dom",
      commonjs: "react-dom",
      amd: "react-dom",
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
};

I am importing the component like this
import Component from "package-name";

I have tried lot of other combinations nothing helped so far.
Please help me to finish this.

Sounds like an issue in your React code, not in your webpack config. What's inside of package-name?

Also getting this Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
But hooks are properly used, for testing purpose i cloned other npm package and tried to install locally and gettting the same error.

Again, that sounds like an error in your React code. Please show us your React code, I don't believe the webpack code matters here.

No, i found this thing related to mutilple react instances in app code while installing the local package. couldn't figure out the solution yet.

Do you have multiple versions of "react" in your package.json? That would be bad if so

no, i had the  same doubt but those are same, will try to give more information about code soon.

Finally fixed by linking the project react to my local library.
The reason for this issue is having multiple react instances while installing local package.

Duplicate React, This problem can also come up when you use npm link
or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts —
one in application folder and one in your library folder. Assuming
myapp and mylib are sibling folders, one possible fix is to run npm
link ../myapp/node_modules/react from mylib. This should make the
library use the application’s React copy.

can see more details here - https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning#duplicate-react
